# Google maps with magento, custom map

Tags: jquery, google-maps, magento

I am making a simple google maps within a page in Magento.

I am referencing both jQuery and Google maps within header.

So far i am rendering the following code:

```
<div id="my_map" style="height: 400px; width: 400px margin-bottom: 0px; border-radius: 10px; margin-top: 30px;">&nbsp;</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        var options = {
            controls: {
                   panControl: false,
                   zoomControl: false,
                   mapTypeControl: false,
                   scaleControl: false,
                   streetViewControl: false,
                           navigationControl: false,
                   overviewMapControl: false
               },
            scrollwheel: false,
            maptype: 'TERRAIN',
            markers: [
                        {
                    latitude: 22.312895, 
                    longitude: 79.439376,
                    html: "Indien",
                    icon: {
                        iconsize: [20, 34],
                        shadowsize: [37, 34],
                        iconanchor: [9, 34],
                        shadowanchor: [19, 34]
                    }
                }
            ],
            latitude: 0.00000, 
            longitude: 0.000000,
            zoom: 2
        };
        jQuery("#my_map").gMap(options);
    });
// ]]></script>
```

This works without any problem in Wordpress, with the exact same refernces.

The page is simply blank when loading the page, but the code is displayed in source code (the rendered code from source-code):

```
<div id="my_map" style="height: 400px; width: 400px margin-bottom: 0px; border-radius: 10px; margin-top: 30px;">&nbsp;</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        var options = {
            controls: {
                   panControl: false,
                   zoomControl: false,
                   mapTypeControl: false,
                   scaleControl: false,
                   streetViewControl: false,
                           navigationControl: false,
                   overviewMapControl: false
               },
            scrollwheel: false,
            maptype: 'TERRAIN',
            markers: [
                        {
                    latitude: 22.312895, 
                    longitude: 79.439376,
                    html: "Indien",
                    icon: {
                        iconsize: [20, 34],
                        shadowsize: [37, 34],
                        iconanchor: [9, 34],
                        shadowanchor: [19, 34]
                    }
                }
            ],
            latitude: 0.00000, 
            longitude: 0.000000,
            zoom: 2
        };
        jQuery("#my_map").gMap(options);
    });
// ]]></script>
```

My question is, what is wrong with the code, since it is simple displaying a blank page?

I have created a [JSFiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/d16q3tsj/) - it seems the same problem is occuring here.

Comment: Where is JQuery included in your code? Where is Maps included in JSFiddle code?

Comment: jQuery is loaded in the header, so it is not present here..
The maps are loaded within the External Resources in fiddle

Comment: you call `.gmap()` but I dont see it defined anywhere

Comment: Hi Craicerjack,
I call gMap(options), and options are defined.

Comment: @Patrick but where did you get gMap from? Its not a maps function as far as I know. You need to create a new map with something like `new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('my_map'),
      options);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento uses mainly prototype.js as javascript, if you wanna try you can check a customization of [Product locator](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/product-locator-1.html)

```
var ScandProductLocator = new Class.create();
ScandProductLocator.prototype = {
initialize : function(data){

if (!data) data = {};
// Own objects
    this.pre_radius = 0;

// Google objects
    this.map = null;
    this.geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    this.infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    // Scand Ltd. position by default
    this.defaultLat = data.lat ? data.lat : 53.889713;
    this.defaultLng = data.lng ? data.lng : 27.536919;
    // count of unique products
    this.productCount = data.count ? data.count : 0;
    // list af addresses
    this.productAddresses = data.addresses ? data.addresses : {};
    // category to display by default
    this.defaultOption =  0;
    // arrays of positions to calculate center of map
    this.lats = [];
    this.lngs = [];
    // list of google.maps.Marker
    this.markers = [];
    // count of horizontal/vertical cells
    this.xCells = 13;
    this.yCells = 10;

    this.currentOption = null;

    this.validate();
},

validate : function () {
    if (this.productCount == 0)
        return;

    var lats = [],
        lngs = [];

    for (var opt_id in this.productAddresses) {
        if (this.productAddresses.hasOwnProperty(opt_id)) {
            this.productAddresses[opt_id].map(function(product){
                if (product.address && !product.lat && !product.lng) {
                    this.geocoder.geocode({'address': product.address.replace(/\<br\>/g, ", ")}, function(results, status) {
                        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                            var item = results.first();
                            product.lat = item.geometry.location.lat();
                            product.lng = item.geometry.location.lng();
                            lats.push(product.lat);
                            lngs.push(product.lng);
                            //this.addMarker(product);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }, this);
        }
    }
},

addProduct : function (opt_id, productsToShow) {
    this.productAddresses[opt_id].collect(function(product){
        if ((product.lat && product.lng) || (product.address !="")) {
            productsToShow[product.product_id] = product;
            this.lats.push(product.lat);
            this.lngs.push(product.lng);

        }
    }, this);
    return productsToShow;
},

showProductsByOption : function (opt_id, no_clear, no_resize) {
    var gridMarkers = {},
        productsToShow = {};
    this.currentOption = opt_id;

    if (!no_clear) {
        $$('#productlocator_categories li a').each(function(e){
            e.setStyle({fontWeight: e === $('cat_'+opt_id) ? 'bold' : 'normal'});
        });

        var i = 0;
        for (i; i < this.markers.length; i++) {
            this.markers[i].setMap(null);
        }

        this.markers = [];
        this.lats = [];
        this.lngs = [];
    }

    if (this.productCount == 0) {
        return;
    }
    else if (opt_id == 0) {
        for (var opt_id in this.productAddresses) {
            productsToShow = this.addProduct(opt_id, productsToShow);
        }
    }
    else if (this.productAddresses.hasOwnProperty(opt_id)) {
        productsToShow = this.addProduct(opt_id, productsToShow);
    }

    if(this.map.getBounds()) {
        var max_lat = this.map.getBounds().getNorthEast().lat(),
            min_lat = this.map.getBounds().getSouthWest().lat(),
            max_lng = this.map.getBounds().getNorthEast().lng(),
            min_lng = this.map.getBounds().getSouthWest().lng();
    }
    else {
        var min_lat = this.lats.min()-5, max_lat = this.lats.max()+5,
            min_lng = this.lngs.min()-5, max_lng = this.lngs.max()+5;
    }

    var lat_dim = (max_lat - min_lat) / this.xCells;
    var lng_dim = (max_lng - min_lng) / this.yCells;

    for (var ndx in productsToShow) {
        if (productsToShow.hasOwnProperty(ndx)) {
            var product = productsToShow[ndx];
            var cell_lng_ind = Math.ceil((product.lng - min_lng) / lng_dim);
            var cell_lat_ind = Math.ceil((product.lat - min_lat) / lat_dim);

            if (!gridMarkers[cell_lng_ind])
                gridMarkers[cell_lng_ind] = {};
            if (!gridMarkers[cell_lng_ind][cell_lat_ind])
                gridMarkers[cell_lng_ind][cell_lat_ind] = {};
            if (!gridMarkers[cell_lng_ind][cell_lat_ind]['products'])
                gridMarkers[cell_lng_ind][cell_lat_ind]['products'] = [];
            gridMarkers[cell_lng_ind][cell_lat_ind]['products'].push(product);
            //this.addMarker(product);
        }
    }

    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    for (var lngName in gridMarkers) {
        for (var latName in gridMarkers[lngName]) {
            var cellText = "",
                lat = 0,
                lng = 0,
                info = "";

            for (var i = 0; i < gridMarkers[lngName][latName]['products'].length; i++) {
                var product = gridMarkers[lngName][latName]['products'][i];
                lat += product.lat;
                lng += product.lng;
                info = '';
                if (product.address && product.address != '')
                    info += '<span class="addr">' + product.address + '</span>';
                if (product.phone && product.phone != '')
                    info += '<span class="phone">' + product.phone + '</span>';

                cellText += "<span class='product_title'>" + (product.product_url ? "<a href='"+product.product_url +"' target='_blank'>" : "");
                cellText +=  product['product_name'];
                cellText += "</span>" +  ((product.product_url)? "</a>":"");
                cellText += "<p class='product_description'>" + info + "</p>";
            }

            if (gridMarkers[lngName][latName]['products'].length > 0) {
                var marker = {
                    'category_name' :   gridMarkers[lngName][latName]['products'][0]['category_name'],
                    'product_id' :  gridMarkers[lngName][latName]['products'][0]['product_id'],
                    'product_name': gridMarkers[lngName][latName]['products'][0]['product_name'],
                    'lat': lat/gridMarkers[lngName][latName]['products'].length,
                    'lng': lng/gridMarkers[lngName][latName]['products'].length,
                    'info': cellText,
                    'items_count': gridMarkers[lngName][latName]['products'].length,
                    'category_lat': gridMarkers[lngName][latName]['products'][0]['category_lat'],
                    'category_long': gridMarkers[lngName][latName]['products'][0]['category_long']
                };
                this.addMarker(marker);
                bounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(marker.lat, marker.lng));




enter code here

    if(!bounds.isEmpty() && (no_resize === undefined || !no_resize)) {
        this.map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }       
},

addMarker : function (product) {
    if (!this.map) return;

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker(
        {
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(product.lat, product.lng),
            map: this.map,
            /*icon.size = new google.maps.Size(35, 35),
            icon.anchor = new google.maps.Point(0, 35),*/
            size : 80,
            title: (product.items_count < 2)? product.product_name : "" + product.items_count + " items",
            icon : 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld='+ product.product_id +'|0431B4|FFFFFF'       
        }
    );






        );


    var context = this;
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        var content = (product.items_count == 1)? product.info : "<p class='items_count'>" + product.items_count + " items</p>" + product.info;
        context.infowindow.setContent("<div class='infowindow'>" + content + "</div>");
        context.infowindow.open(context.map, marker);
    });



    var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
          map: this.map,
          radius: this.pre_radius,    // 10 miles in metres 16093
          fillColor: '#E6E6E6',
          fillOpacity: 0.0 ,
          strokeOpacity : 0.1,
          strokeWeight: 1,
          strokeWidth:1
        });
    circle.bindTo('center', marker_cat, 'position');        



    this.markers.push(marker);
    this.lats.push(product.lat);
    this.lngs.push(product.lng);

    this.markers.push(marker_cat);
    this.lats.push(product.category_lat);
    this.lngs.push(product.category_long);
},




draw : function () {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(this.defaultLat, this.defaultLng);
    disableDefaultUI:false;
    var map_options = {

            panControl:true,
            zoomControl:true,
            mapTypeControl:true,
            scaleControl:true,
            streetViewControl:true,
            overviewMapControl:true,
            rotateControl:true,     

      center: latlng,
      zoom: 180,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var circle = new google.maps.Circle({

          map: this.map,
          radius: 16093,    // 10 miles in metres 16093
          fillColor: '#AA0000'
        });
        circle.bindTo('center', map_options, 'position');


    this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), map_options);

    this.showProductsByOption(this.defaultOption);

    /* Add rebuild markers (regroup) on resize map */
    var context = this;
    google.maps.event.addListener(this.map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
        if(context.zoom !== this.getZoom()) {
            context.zoom = this.getZoom();
            context.showProductsByOption(context.currentOption, false, true);
        }
    });
},

changeCircle : function (radius) {
    /*Takes de radius from  function calcRadius(radio)*/



    this.pre_radius = radius;

}
}
```

you can see that in this case that id its map_canvas and check mainly if like the functions , i hope that this code will help you

Answer (score 0):

To use gMap plugin you must include it from http://gmap.nurtext.de/js/jquery.gmap-1.1.0-min.js.

So, there are **three** components:

1. Google Maps library
2. JQuery framework
3. JQuery gMaps plugin